# Failed to Add a New Scaffolded Item from a different Project into my Web Project (MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When I try to create a `New Scaffolded Item` in my website project, I get the following message:

> `Error`
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'There was an error getting the type '`SomeProjectInMySolution`.`SomeModelInThatProject`'.
>
> Try rebuilding the project.'

Now, It seems that is not able to create it because is in a different context.

I tried doing what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393721/1188208) suggested. But, failed.

What else could I try?

This is how I am filling the generation form:

[image]

**Note:**

I am using:

- `Entity Framework6 6.1.3`
- `EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator:` to generate the context in that particular project where it exists.
- All of my projects are buing built in 64-bit platform.
- I also have the correct `ConnectionString` in my `Web.config` in the Website Project as well.

Thank you so much

**Updates:**

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259374/scaffolding-auto-code-generator-completely-broken). But, nothing.

I noticed that when trying to create the item, the console outputs this:

> Attempting to install version '6.1.1' of 'EntityFramework' but the project already includes a different version. Skipping...

However, all my projects have `6.1.3`. Tried downgrading to `6.1.1`. But, still not working. Why is it even displaying that message?

`<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />`

**DefaultAppPool Advanced Settings:**

[image]

Comment: Have you rebuilt the project and tried again?

Comment: You can reference this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259374/scaffolding-auto-code-generator-completely-broken

Comment: Tried that as well. I also tried downgrading EntityFramework from 6.1.3 to 6.1.1. But, nothing.

Comment: I remember running into this exact error message. I "rebuild" the solution and close/reopen visual studio and then it is running well.

Comment: I've tried it already too many times :( but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: also try seeing this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841831/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-generator-try-rebuilding-the-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this horrible problem:

Several posts were sure that it was related to the `x64` platform thing. So, in a last and desperate attempt I just changed the platform to `Any CPU` (of every project), then I run the Scaffolded item generator, and then finally switched back `64-bit`.

I am not sure why this works. My coworker mentioned that Visual Studio was built in 32-bit and maybe that's what caused the issue. I really don't know. But, I hope this helps anyone in the future with the same problem.

Thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with generating views from a controller in asp.net .

The problem here was, that my model class inherited from a class outside project, when i commented the inheritance out of the class, the generation worked and i was able to make the inheritance again.

like this:

```
public class Employee //: PersonBase {...}
```

so i generated and then i deleted the Comment slashes.

```
public class Employee : PersonBase {...}
```

Do not know if it helps you but it is worth a try.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. However, my models don't inherit from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent whole day with the same issue and it turns out to be a bug in MVC scaffolding which is already reported.
For details and work around please see the link below:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4336